# check value of select box at init and when changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to initiate some tests and execute some changes at init phase when the document has loaded to check the value of a select box and also when the box changes. Here is the way I do it and it is working fine but I am wondering if there is an easier way to do it because I have to do it through a function and call it at start and also calling it when a button is changing.

```
// In case this is baseline, project or pre-sales, we will have different text to be selected

  function project_type_value_check() { 
    switch ($("#project_type option:selected").val()){
      case "Baseline":
        $('#revenue_text').text("MRC (k€)");
        $("#revenue").attr("placeholder", "MRC (k€)");
        break;
      case "Pre-sales":
        alert('presales');
        break;
      default:
        $('#revenue_text').text("Revenue (k€)");
        $("#revenue").attr("placeholder", "Revenue (k€)");
    } 
  }

  // This is when the page loads
  project_type_value_check();

  // This is when the select box changes
  $('#project_type').change(function() {
    project_type_value_check();
  });
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong here but you can just trigger change event instead of calling method. so if your onchange method getting more complex, your code can handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more elegant

```js
var vals = {"Baseline":"MRC (k€)","Pre-sales":"Presales"}
$(function() {
  $('#project_type').on("change",function() {
    var val = this.value || "Baseline"
    var show = vals[val]
    if (val=="Pre-sales") alert(show);
    else { 
      $('#revenue_text').text(show);
      $("#revenue").attr("placeholder", show);
    }  
  }).trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="project_type">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="Baseline">Baseline</option>
  <option value="Pre-sales">Pre-sales</option>  
</select><br/>
<span id="revenue_text"></span>
<input type="text" id="revenue" value=""/>
```